# How to 'Find And Push' element in an array inside of another array in a document using LINQ to MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to push an element to an array inside another array inside a document using LINQ with latest MongoDb driver

here is the code:

```
public class Contract : BaseDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    ...
    public List<Payment> Payments {get;set;}
}

public class Payment : BaseDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public double TotalPaymentAmount {get;set;}
    public DateTime PaymentWorthDate {get;set;}
    ...
    public List<PaymentTransaction> PaymentTransactions {get;set;}
}

public class PaymentTransaction 
{
    public double AmountPaid {get;set;}
    public DateTime TransactionDateTime {get;set;}
}
```

So how to push new `PaymentTransaction` to a specific `Payment` in a particular `Contract` using 'LINQ Expression' ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LINQ` stands for Language-Intergrated Query while you're trying to update the document so actually you need `UpdateOne` method. Since you have more than one nested array you can leverage regular query to identify `Contract` along with the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to indicate which `Payment` (nested object) should be modified.

.NET MongoDB driver offers a special syntax where you can pass `-1` as an index to indicate that this item will be identified based on filtering condition. Try:

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<Contract>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, contractId) &
                filterBuilder.ElemMatch(doc => doc.Payments, el => el.Id == paymentId);

var updateBuilder = Builders<Contract>.Update;
var update = updateBuilder.Push(doc => doc.Payments[-1].PaymentTransactions, new PaymentTransaction());

col.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```