# LINQ query to push an item to the array of a Mongo Document

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to push a ProductPhoto inside the Product using LINQ. Here is my model:

```
public class Product
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Detail { get; set; }
   public List<ProductPhoto> ProductPhotos { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPhoto
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this with the LINQ query? I am expecting the result to be something like this.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('602d2149e773f2a3990b47f5'),
    Name: 'Some name',
    Detail: 'Some description',
    ProductPhotos: [
      { _id: ObjectId('602d2149e773f2a3990b47f5'), Url: 'Some URL' }
    ] 
}
```

Next time when I add a new ProductPhoto, then there will be two elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to similar question:

[How to 'Find And Push' element in an array inside of another array in a document using LINQ to MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840324/how-to-find-and-push-element-in-an-array-inside-of-another-array-in-a-document)

You can achieve this with something like this:

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<Product>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Id, productId);
var updateBuilder = Builders<Product>.Update;
var update = updateBuilder.Push(doc => doc.ProductPhotos, productPhoto);
Products.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```